# refactor/rename script for rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a refactor/rename script similar to https://github.com/hiroshi/script-refactor that works with rails 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would encourage you to try RubyMine IDE from JetBrains.  It has refactoring (such as name change) built-in and it usually does a fantastic job.

We use RubyMine as our default IDE at my work (about 20 rails engineers) and everyone loves it.